# GreyBox when interacting with PowerBI Embedded Report (WKWebView)

Tags: ios, objective-c, powerbi-embedded

I'm trying to embed Power BI report & dashboard in a custom mobile app. I'm using webview (WKWebView) because I see there is no API besides Javascript to display the report in my (iOS) mobile apps. The embedded report is running, but i found this grey box when I try to interact with it and the user find it a little bit disturbing. (
[check out this video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uxPO9VmAQe-bfJiAhwCPdsZD8EbdoK70/view)
).
I put the html file in the asset (xcode project) and then load it into a WebView.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet WKWebView *dashboardWV;
NSString *filePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"BI" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"powerbi"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: filePath];
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[dashboardWV loadRequest:request];
```

Is there another way to embed the report to my mobile apps without webview / to get the same user experience with the PowerBI Mobile apps?
I see that the [PowerBI Mobile App](https://itunes.apple.com/eg/app/microsoft-power-bi/id929738808?mt=8) (unlike mine) run smoothly in the iPad without the Grey Boxes.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue, we are working on fixing it (no ETA yet).

Comment: Hi Dikla, thanks for the response. I'm curious about the difference in the PowerBI Mobile App and the Embedded Apps. Is the PowerBI Mobile App using a webview too?

Comment: PowerBI Mobile App is not using the embedded solution.